# Cross-thread operation not valid (How to access WinForm elements from another modules events?)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, thread-safety

I have a module with an event for serial port signal

```
serialPort.DataReceived.AddHandler(SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceived));
```

where DataReceived is

```
let DataReceived a b =
    rxstring <- serialPort.ReadExisting()
    arrayRead <- System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rxstring)
    if arrayRead.[0] = 0x0Auy then
        ProcessData(a, null)
```

and ProcessData is invoking WinForms method

```
let ProcessData(a, b) =
    dataProcessor.Invoke(a, b) |> ignore
```

which is

```
private void ProcessData(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   byte[] m = Core.ncon.ArrayRead;
   switch (m[1]) {
      case 0x01: {
          if (m.Length > 5) {
             int myval = BitConverter.ToInt32(m, 3);
             textBox1.Text += " val: " + myval.ToString() + " ";
```

but when it's trying to access textBox1 I'm getting:

**Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**

So the question is, How to access WinForm elements from another modules events?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use the forms dispatcher.

```
FormContaingTheTextbox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate(){
    textBox1.Text += " val: " + myval.ToString() + " ";
}));
```

This makes that code run in the forms thread instead of yours.

Comment: Then you need to make your code raise an event which the form can listen to and then do the invoke with. Your module shouldn't be trying to change properties on the form directly.

Answer (score 22):

Try Using below Code:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() 
{ 
//Access your controls
}));
```

hope this helps